# problem installing eclipse groovy plugin in galileo

Tags: eclipse, groovy

I'm trying to install groovy plugin in eclipse 3.5 using [this update site](https://web.archive.org/web/20091002000303/http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.5/).

It does install but when it tries to restart I get an exception.

```
!SESSION Sat Aug 29 15:47:17 PDT 2009 ------------------------------------------ 
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2009-08-29 15:47:17.287
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform: 
!STACK java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter 
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200) 
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
```

I tried to start using `-clean` options,deleted workspace no luck

Did anyone get this too??

Comment: It would help you if can provide details of the exception that Eclipse throws.

Comment: !SESSION Sat Aug 29 15:47:17 PDT 2009 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2009-08-29 15:47:17.287
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
 at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
 at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
I tried to start using -clean options,deleted workspace no luck.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing a class or a jar required by the plugin; I'm not sure which one though, since the stacktrace does not indicate any such plugin specific class. You could attempt the following:

1. Examine the .log file of the workspace to view any additional details of the exception.
2. Verify if all the Groovy Eclipse plugin jars are present in the plugins and features directory of the Eclipse installation.
3. Start Eclipse with the consolelog and debug switches, and pipe the output to a debug log file. Examine for anything indicative of the problem in the logfile; if needed post the log file. The command to start Eclipse in this mode would be

   ```
   $eclipse -consolelog -debug | tee debugfile.log
   ```
4. Install the plugin on a clean installation of Eclipse.

Comment: thanks Vineet, my bad i am using mac so i tried to install galileo for 32-bit, mine is 64 bit hope now the problem should not be there

Comment: narup, I've updated the answer. You can check if the consolelog and debug switches on the Eclipse runtime will provide more info about the failure, in case you haven't managed to resolve it.

Comment: cool let me try again, even with the 64-bit version i got the error.

Comment: i am getting lot of failures on equinox and osgi jars not sure why, but after i tried to install more plugin from galileo update site i got few more exception

Comment: Is the exception stack too big to paste here? If so, you can put it up at http://paste-it.net/

Answer (score 0):

OK now finally i fixed it after 2 days of war with eclipse, so for some reason when groovy plugin was installed eclipse modified `config.ini` file inside configuration folder
so I have to modify `config.ini` file to replace `osgi.bundles` value with

```
osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.100.v20090520-1905.jar@1\:start,reference\:file\:plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.core_3.5.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.apache.commons.collections_3.2.1.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.apache.commons.lang_2.3.0.v200803061910.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy_1.7.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35/@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ant_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35/@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.codeassist.completion_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.codebrowsing_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.core_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.core.help_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35/@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.cstviewer_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.refactoring_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.codehaus.groovy.eclipse.ui_2.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4,reference\:file\:/Applications/galileo/plugins/org.eclipse.jdt.groovy.core_1.0.0.xx-20090828-1900-e35.jar@4
```

By default `osgi.bundles` value is `osgi.bundles=reference\:file\:org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator_1.0.100.v20090520-1905.jar@1\:start` but as soon as I installed groovy plugin I had a modified value which caused eclipse fali to start.

now my eclipse starts and i see the groovy features too..

Comment: Great, good to know that it works now. In fact, you could re-word it as an answer to your own question, and accept it :)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with installing the CVS plugin on a Eclipse Platform installation running TeXlipse. Turns out, after installing CVS, the installer had modified not the `osgi.bundles`, but the `osgi.framework`.

`/Applications/TeXlipse/configuration/config.ini` said:

```
 osgi.framework=file\:/Applications/TeXlipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.5.2.R35x_v20100126.jar
```

and it was supposed to say

```
 osgi.framework=file\:/Applications/TeXlipse/plugins/org.eclipse.osgi_3.5.2.R35x_v20100126.jar
```